# Google Ads Remarketing Tag not working - only in preview and debug mode

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm trying to implement an Google Ads Remarketing tag in Google Tag Manager (GTM). I have tried with and without dataLayer values - I've tried all sorts of triggers.. Page View, DOM Ready, Window Loaded - All pages.. even tried tag sequencing (after a tag that works fine). The funny thing is - I can see the tag i preview and debug mode (before and after i publish) - as long as I am in preview and debug mode - everything looks fine - also in Google Tag Assistant. But when I try in another browser og close the preview and debug mode - I can't see it in Google Tag Assistant - And so far I can see, it doesn't work (nothing to be seen in the Network tab in DevTools (Chrome), when I search for the conversion id). Something must be blocking it - I just can't figure it out. This is the site https://mackabler.dk/ - the tag is published. The shop is running on Prestashop. Any suggestion on where to look or investigate?

Screenshots (sorry danish language - ask if you need translation for anything):

[Remarketing tag](https://prntscr.com/oznj9g)

[Trigger](https://prntscr.com/oznl8s)

[variable for dynamic remarketing](https://prntscr.com/oznlp6)

Comment: A conversion tag (995907503) is visible in your GTM file. If it were blocked by the browser the network tab would show it as block, so this is more likely to be a configuration issue. Can you maybe show a screenshot of your tag configuration? And while  probably not related  to this specific problem, your page seems to have two  gtm.js events.

Comment: I already have a Google Ads Conversion Tag, if that's what you're referring to - but that is only triggered on the order confirmed page. I think it's likely it's blocked by something else .js going on somewhere. Just seems so weird, that everything looks fine, as long as I'm in preview and debug (with everything published). Analytics & Google Optimize work fine with the exact same trigger - conversion linker also has the same trigger.. right now it's "DOM Ready - All pages" if domain contains "mackabler.dk" (there's also mackabler.se etc.). Where did you see the two gtm.js?

Comment: I posted the screenshots in the original post (I'm a noob here)

Comment: Had a similar issue, turned out some of the calls were blocked by the CSP header. Are you sure nothing is blocked in the Network tab?

Comment: It doesn't even show up in the Network tab. I check on other pages where it works fine and on those it shows up in the Network tab. It's really weird. Something is blocking it - just can't figure out what. But thanks for you suggestion anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have installed Google Site Tag (gtag.js) and Google Ads re-marketing tag on the same website. This could be the reason that your tags are not firing correctly.

Whenever you add 2 tags for the same task then those tags create discrepancy won't work correctly.

The Google Site tag (gtag.js) is a web tagging library for Google's site measurement, conversion tracking, and re-marketing products.

Not a full and exact information but you may find relevant information on this article - https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/3103357

Note - Please check "Updating your tag" section